# WinApi нажатие Ctrl + -

Tags: c#, winapi

Доброго времени суток. Пишу небольшого автокликера для мобильной игры. Игра запускается в эмуляторе Bluestacks. Мне требуется передать нажатие на клавиатуре Ctrl + - (VK_OEM_MINUS = 0xBD). Посмотрел что происходит в Spy++ когда нажимаю эти клавиши, вот результат.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее набросал кусок кода который повторяет эти же действия. Вот что происходит когда программно пытаюсь послать эти кнопки в окно эмулятора.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сверял, все идентично. Но от куда-то берется WM_CHAR и так нечего не происходит. 1 кнопка работает, проверял на VK_DOWN = 0x28, а сочетание клавиш не как не получается запустить. Вот кусок колхозного кода.

```
public static void SendKey(VirtualKeys key, bool ctrl = false)
    {
        if (BlueStacksHelper.IsRunning)
        {
            int wKey = (((short)key) & 0xFF);
            int lKey = 0x000000001 | ((int)Win32.MapVirtualKey((uint)wKey, 0) << 16);
            int wCtrl = (((short)VirtualKeys.VK_CONTROL) & 0xFF);
            int lCtrl = 0x000000001 | ((int)Win32.MapVirtualKey((uint)wCtrl, 0) << 16);

            if (ctrl)
                Win32.PostMessage(BlueStacksHelper._handleWindow, Win32.WM_KEYDOWN, ((IntPtr) VirtualKeys.VK_CONTROL), (IntPtr)lCtrl);


            Thread.Sleep(65);
            Win32.PostMessage(BlueStacksHelper._handleWindow, Win32.WM_KEYDOWN, ((IntPtr)wKey), (IntPtr) lKey);
            lKey = (int)(0xC0000001 | (int)Win32.MapVirtualKey((uint)wKey, 0) << 16);
            Win32.PostMessage(BlueStacksHelper._handleWindow, Win32.WM_KEYUP, ((IntPtr)wKey), (IntPtr) lKey);

            lCtrl = (int)(0xC0000001 | (int)Win32.MapVirtualKey((uint)wCtrl, 0) << 16);
            if (ctrl)
                Win32.PostMessage(BlueStacksHelper._handleWindow, Win32.WM_KEYUP, ((IntPtr)VirtualKeys.VK_CONTROL), (IntPtr)lCtrl);
            Thread.Sleep(65);
        }
    }
```

Что я делаю не так? Ведь вроде все идентично, только у меня WM_CHAR непонятно от куда передается.

**UPD**
WM_CHAR это char символ - который я нажимаю на клавиатуре. Но почему и он передается?

Comment: Я думаю ответ прост: эта схема не работает. WM_CHAR посылается из-за вызова TranslateMessage в целевом приложении, которая считывание состояние Ctrl напрямую с клавиатуры, а не из сообщений. Для начала, SendKeys из Winforms пробовали?

Comment: SendKeys не подходит для моих целей, нужно посылать нажатие именно окну которое будет на заднем плане, так как во время работы автокликера за компьютером будет вестись работа.

Comment: Ну, значит вам придется вручную реализовать то, что делает SendKeys, только для любого окна. Это называется Journal Hooks: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7466/Writing-a-Macro-Recorder-Player-using-Win-Journa